# Android Studio, interrogate if button was clicked

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out, how I could interrogate if one of two buttons were clicked.
Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one of the buttons is clicked, set a variable into true, for example

```
boolean aButtonWasClicked = false;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
          aButtonWasClicked = true;
     }
});
```

So now, you have stored in `aButtonWasClicked` the result of the "interrogation". So you can do different things depending on it:

```
if(aButtonWasClicked){
  //yes
} else {
  //no
}
```